# Writing Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, dictionary

I have iterated over a database and created a dictionary. The key is records in field 1 and the values are the averages of in each column for their corresponding record in field 1. The questions I have is what is the best way to output my dictionary to a table?

```
myDict = {}
def Calculate(key, fields, dt):
    results = {}
    for rec in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, "*"):
    header[names] = row[1]
    if results.has_key(key):
            result = results[key]
            i = 0
        while i < len(fields):
            result[i] += rec[fields[i]]
            i += 1
            result[len(fields)] += 1
    else:
            temp = []
            i = 0
            while i < len(fields):
                temp.append(rec[fields[i]])
                i += 1
            temp.append (1)
            results[rec[key]] = temp

    endResults = {}
    for k in results:
        j = 0
        tempEndResults = []
        while j < len(results[k]) - 1: 
            tempEndResults.append(results[k][j] / results[k][len(results[k])-1])
            j += 1
        endResults[k] = tempEndResults
        i += 1
    return endResults

Calculate(1, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23], myDict)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of you code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. When you are posting code, it's generally best to avoid tabs altogether, and an indentation of 4 spaces per level is most common. You can indent code you prepared by copy'n'paste into the SO edit box, selecting the code, and then indenting it with the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  As it stands, the first `while` loop is incorrectly indented (or the lines before it are), and the tail of the code is all wrong too; the `return endResults` is not in the scope of a function definition. Please be careful when presenting questions!

Comment: Also it helps everybody if you are very clear about your question. In this case, what would you like the csv to look like?

Answer (score 1):

> The questions I have is what is the best way 
>   to output my dictionary to a table?

To create a CSV, you can use a nested loop to print the inner values in tabular form:

```
for k, seq in myDict.items():
    for elem in seq:
        print '%s,%s' % (k, elem)
```

This should give you a nice looking CSV table.